# Instantaneously sync data between two or more redis servers

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, redis, synchronization

I am running multiple redis servers, but I want to sync the data between multiple redis server with very less lag or no lag. To make a point I am using this model in the production. I am not able to figure out the master - master syn. I am running on aws ec2 ubuntu instances.

Kindly help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Redis replication, 
you can create whatever slaved you want and they will ping the master at every second to check for updates from the master, the master will remember when each slave last ping the master,

For configure this you can check this:  [Redis Replication Documentation](http://redis.io/topics/replication)